# Calendar Backup and Restore

Tags: android, calendar

I am building a application which takes a backup of calendar & restores it on demand.

How can I achieve this in Android? Are there any api's which imports/exports contacts just like for Contacts ?

Comment: I am trying to take backup and restore Calendar using Calendar Provider but not work proper. you solved this problem plz help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've got all the data you would like to put back into the calendar, you can use the [google-api-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) to access the users [google calendar](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html) and put your events in it. Here's an [example of using it in android](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default).

Comment: link not working , please help